# [Meteor][jQuery] Synchronize the scrolling of two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

How do you use jQuery to synchronize the scrolling of two divs of a template in meteor?  Where should this jQuery code be placed in the .js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isClient) {
    Template.templatename.rendered = function() {
        $('#masterDivId').on('scroll', function() {
            $('#slaveDivId').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
        });
    }
}
```

Add vice versa to make them co-dependant